# How to check if Keras backend is tensorflow or theano

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, theano

I want to check in code what backend keras is using. Whether it is tensorflow or theano? How can I get this?

The code [here](https://github.com/coxlab/prednet/blob/master/prednet.py#L168) uses `K._BACKEND`, however I'm getting an error saying that attribute not found. My Keras version is 2.2.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [here](https://github.com/coxlab/prednet/issues/82), the following works

```
from keras import backend as K

print(K.backend())
```