Error when trying to save and then load_model using keras: 'ValueError: A total of 1 objects could not be loaded.'
I am trying to save a DNN model and then later load the model using the keras method load_model.  The following is a simple example copied from the Keras documentation.
import keras

model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.layers.Dense(5, input_shape=(3,)),
        keras.layers.Softmax(),
    ],
)
model.save("model.keras")
loaded_model = keras.saving.load_model("model.keras")

Unfortunately, running this code in VS Code or IDLE on my PC produces the following error:  ValueError: A total of 1 objects could not be loaded.  A randomly selected "Example error message" is also displayed, but does not appear to be particularly helpful.
How can I save and load the model without the above ValueError, preferably using the .keras extension?
(There are several other loosely related SO questions, such as this one, but these generally concern the legacy extension .h5 rather than the recommended native format .keras.)

Solution.  For me, the error disappeared after uninstalling Keras 3.1.1 and installing Keras 3.5.0.

I had the same problem while using keras with torch backend. I'm quite new to this and I don't exactly know the reason but changing the backend to tensorflow solved it for me.
You have instructions for how to change the keras backend here or here.
You can also read the documentation here.
I hope it helps.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

In my case, my backend is already tensorflow (assuming that the approach to check this described here is valid: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66685496/how-to-check-if-keras-backend-is-tensorflow-or-theano).
